# What is the optimum number of Maven threads in practice?

Tags: maven

If your Maven build is amiable to it, you can use the -T option to run in multiple threads.

Examples I've seen use `-T 1C` or `-T 2C`. This makes sense to me if the build is IO bound rather than CPU bound, and the machine is exclusively running the build. What is optimum in practice for a developer machine?

Comment: First a build is always IO bound cause the most important thing to speed up builds is to have fast io which means in practice having fast hard disk (ssd)...The optimimum depends on the modules which can be built in parallel...I would suggest to start with `-T 4` and take a look at the total build time...make a try to change to `-T 6` and see if the total build time decreases..if not change to `-T 5` and check if it's faster than `-T 4`...

Comment: Its not the hard drive speed, it's the constant checking of remote repositories.